# Using C++ Modules TS with standard headers on linux

Tags: c++, linux, c++-modules

I am testing a simple C++ module using the modules ts:

```
export module strings;
#include <string>
```

When I try to compile that with clang (trunk) and GCC 7.2 headers on linux, I get this:

```
clang++ -std=c++2a -fmodules-ts -fprebuilt-module-path=. --precompile -x c++-module -o strings.pcm ../../src/base/strings.cc
In file included from ../../src/base/strings.cc:2:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/c++/7.2.0/string:52:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/c++/7.2.0/bits/basic_string.h:39:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/c++/7.2.0/ext/atomicity.h:35:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7.2.0/bits/gthr.h:148:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7.2.0/bits/gthr-default.h:101:1: error: weakref declaration must have internal linkage
__gthrw(pthread_once)
^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7.2.0/bits/gthr-default.h:99:23: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw'
#define __gthrw(name) __gthrw2(__gthrw_ ## name,name,name)
                      ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7.2.0/bits/gthr-default.h:90:46: note: expanded from macro '__gthrw2'
  static __typeof(type) name __attribute__ ((__weakref__(#name2))); \
                                             ^
```

I tried to pre-include `<bits/gthr-default.h>` (before the `export module`), but then I get errors regarding `time.h` and `sched.h`...

Does anyone know a way to get this to compile?

(For the complete error message, see here: https://godbolt.org/g/wfjmpW)

Comment: I found a hacky solution (https://godbolt.org/g/vWA2aW). It works as long as I don't need to `#include <ctime>` inside the module...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record, I found a (somewhat) better [solution](https://godbolt.org/g/6ZwGTw):

```
export module strings;
#if defined(__GXX_WEAK__)
#include <bits/gthr-default.h>
#endif

#include <string>
```

This works even if I need to `#include <ctime>` inside the module.